# What's the difference between the softmax and logsig activation functions for neural networks (patternnet)?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, softmax

I set up the network using the `softmax` function, and I noticed that after training the network, the output layer activation function just changes to `logsig`. What could be the reason for that?

My data is scaled between 0 and 1.

Comment: When and how does this change?

Comment: When I use view(net) after building the network, the activation function in the output layer is softmax. When the training window pops up, the activation function in the network diagram, appears to be logsig instead of softmax.